# Unable to run pycel example

Tags: python, pycel

I have tried run the pycel example in a clean virtualenv, after installing pycel package from source. The result is:

```
    (py_cel) C:\Users\pena\Downloads\pycel\example>python --version
    Python 3.9.7
    
    (py_cel) C:\Users\pena\Downloads\pycel\example>pip list
    Package          Version
    ---------------- -------
    decorator        5.1.1
    et-xmlfile       1.1.0
    networkx         2.4
    numpy            1.23.4
    openpyxl         3.2.0b1
    pip              22.3.1
    pycel            1.0b23
    python-dateutil  2.8.2
    ruamel.yaml      0.17.21
    ruamel.yaml.clib 0.2.7
    setuptools       65.5.1
    six              1.16.0
    wheel            0.38.4
    
    (py_cel) C:\Users\pena\Downloads\pycel\example>python example.py
    Loading C:\Users\pena\Downloads\pycel\example\example.xlsx...
    C:\Users\pena\Documents\Heis\documentator\environ\py_cel\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.2.0b1-py3.9.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:332: UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
      warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\pena\Downloads\pycel\example\example.py", line 40, in <module>
        excel = ExcelCompiler(filename=fname)
      File "C:\Users\pena\Documents\Heis\documentator\environ\py_cel\lib\site-packages\pycel-1.0b23-py3.9.egg\pycel\excelcompiler.py", line 69, in __init__
        self.excel.load()
      File "C:\Users\pena\Documents\Heis\documentator\environ\py_cel\lib\site-packages\pycel-1.0b23-py3.9.egg\pycel\excelwrapper.py", line 241, in load
        self.load_array_formulas()
      File "C:\Users\pena\Documents\Heis\documentator\environ\py_cel\lib\site-packages\pycel-1.0b23-py3.9.egg\pycel\excelwrapper.py", line 246, in load_array_formulas
        for address, props in ws.formula_attributes.items():
    AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'formula_attributes'
```

I would like to know how to run this example. Thanks.

Comment: What is the code inside *example.py* ?

Comment: @raiyan22 It is the original example from repository: https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel/blob/b093fc5a7c3c1c72d94f58ed71bf67d985d95291/example/example.py